# JSON Object to typescript class in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on converting the JSON to typescript interface and unbale to map the same.

I have the below format JSON string which allows array

```
{
  "abc": [
    {"key": "a", "value": "a"},
    {"key": "b", "value": "b"},
    {"key": "c", "value": "c"}
  ],
  "cdf": [
    {"key": "a", "value": "a"},
    {"key": "b", "value": "b"},
    {"key": "c", "value": "c"}
  ],
}
```

I would like to define the class for it in the react but facing issues. Could any one please help to declare the typescript class for the above JSON.

**Edited:**
Please note keys are not static

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since this is a JSON, it is a string. We can't assign a json to a variable in JS without converting it to JS object or array. If you want to assign this to variable however, make it as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
type Inner = {key: string, value: string}

type Thing = {
    abc: Inner[],
    cdf: Inner[]
}
```

for not static keys

```
type Thing = Record<string,Inner[]>
// or
type Thing = {
   [K: string]: Inner[]
}
```

you can learn more at the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html)

Comment: thanks for the code and it response is working fine but if I get the array of keys. Please find by edited question @ertucode